# Where to download a CLEAN version of Win10 Media Creation Tool 1909?

Tags: windows-10, malware

Can anyone tell me where I can download a clean version of Windows 10 Media Creation Tool 1909?
The version that I currently downloaded is shown to include a PUA upon scanning the file via MetaDefender. 
I am seeing  "***BrowserModifier/Toolbar!khSzOxHe / W32.Toolbar.CrossRider.AE.czia.mg***" show up as a threat after being scanned.

Thanks.

Comment: Use the Microsoft Media Creation link. That is the true source for what you want and we use it ourselves.

Comment: Hi John. Thank you for the quick response. The source I downloaded from was the MS site itself. Here is the link I downloaded from - https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=691209

Comment: @Inanetsh - What you have run into is a false positive.  **If you downloaded it from Microsoft then the file is clean.**

Comment: @Inanetsh files can be marked as a threat because they are flagged when they are downloaded from the internet. They are not always malicious. If it is from Microsoft, it is clean. You can check by clicking the lock icon at the top of the search bar in your browser and see if the security certificate is from Microsoft.